# Mapped type producing unexpected results when created from generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, template-literals

I'm using static objects to describe contract definitions, and attempting to generate types based on them. These contracts can optionally have some options, which I want to describe using an array of option names. I then want to use this array to construct a type for passing in option values. All options should be required. See the following code:

```js
const definition  = { optionNames: ['a', 'b'] as const }

type OptionNames = typeof definition['optionNames'][number]
// type OptionNames = "a" | "b"

type Options = Record<OptionNames, string>
// type Options = {
//   a: string;
//   b: string;
// }
```

So far so good, I can construct the Options type statically without any issues. However when I try to do the same with generic types, I'm getting some unexpected results:

```js
interface Definition { optionNames?: readonly string[] }

type ConstructOptions<T1 extends Definition, T2 = T1['optionNames'][number]> = T2 extends string | number | symbol ? Record<T2, string> : {}

type GenericOptions = ConstructOptions<typeof definition>
// type GenericOptions = Record<"a", string> | Record<"b", string>
```

I would expect GenericOptions to be the same as Options, however the result is a union of Records which each only have 1 of the options as a required key. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a tuple to make sure that each constituent is not considered separately:

```
type ConstructOptions<T1 extends Definition, T2 = T1['optionNames'][number]> = [T2] extends [string | number | symbol] ? Record<T2, string> : {}
```

Full example:

```
const definition  = { optionNames: ['a', 'b'] as const }

interface Definition { optionNames?: readonly string[] }

type ConstructOptions<T1 extends Definition, T2 = T1['optionNames'][number]> = [T2] extends [string | number | symbol] ? Record<T2, string> : {}

type GenericOptions = ConstructOptions<typeof definition>;
```

A weird thing you would probably never think of, but it works. Just TypeScript things here ✌️.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwGYEswqi8MYF4YDeMIADpuAHICGAtghAFwwDaA5FawDQysBGrAXRhUIMUJFgBfALAAoOWigIATkirAEMACLI0GLGELEyB6nQgB+JsoRU44ADYBPGNGVoA5syEz5sqE4kmgDC4G4ArsBQAPImYQA8ACoAjDAIAB5KYHCiOqjo5GDciQBMeDApbKSFZvSCzGDhNLwqAgB85cylQhlZOSxunjAAPjCNzSojrk7NIA5CFjAASgigynBJJdyDYB4dTAS+cgFBMADiCGAqKMCxhaL4oRLKkTFxkPEnCCBI8LoFBjaAG4gA)

By the way, you might want to fix that error in there with `NonNullable` or `Required` ;)

Comment: It should be noted that this is due to the distributive nature of conditional types and "tuple-wrapping" naked types prevents this. More here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29368